# Callback or completion event for Ti.Platform.openUrl or Ti.App.fireEvent

Tags: events, callback, titanium

Does anyone know a way of finding out precisely when either a Ti.Platform.openUrl or Ti.App.fireEvent finishes?  Something like a callback or an completion event?  Thanks.

Nathan

Answer (score 0):

App-level events are **global to your app**. They are accessible in all contexts, functional scopes, CommonJS modules, and so forth. You can fire them and listen for them via the Ti.App module as follows.

```
//Creating an app level custom event
Ti.App.addEventListener('myAppEvent', myCallBack);

//Fire the event like
Ti.App.fireEvent('myAppEvent');

//Callback function of your custom event
function myCallBack(e){
    alert("In call back. App level event get fired!!!");
}
```

Please refer [Event handling](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Event+Handling#EventHandling) in Titanium for more details